# $(\{-1,1\} \cdot)^2$ what does this notation for this group infer

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

$(\{-1,1\}, \cdot)^2$ what does this notation for this group infer

I need to show this is isomorphic to the Klein-4 group $V_4$

the power is what throws me off. is this another way to denote $(\{-1,1,i,-i\}, \cdot)$

Or something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be two copies of this group - the cartesian product.

Just as $\mathbb{R}$ is the real line and $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the plane.

Comment: so $\{(1,1),(-1,-1),(1,-1),(-1,1)\}$

Comment: Yes, which is just $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$

Comment: Comment: That's the set, but the group operation isn't explicit. Without that, you haven't specified a group.

Comment: Yes. I would assume this obvious from context though.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume it's the group $\{ (1,1), (1, -1), (-1, -1), (-1, 1)\}$ under pointwise multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Literally, it's just $\{-1,1\}\times\{-1,1\}$ with tuple multiplication $\odot$ defined component-wise: $$(a,b)\odot(c,d)\stackrel{\textrm{def}}=(a\cdot c,b\cdot d).$$